# HTML5: receiving mouseUp events on element without mouseDown event

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

If i perform mouse down on element A and release the mouse when i am on element B, neither of the elements receive the mouseUp event.
Is it possible that one of them will receive the event (it does not matter to me which of the two)?

Comment: The element you release on should receive mouseup event, unless the mousedown event is cancelled on the target.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the elements receive the mouseup event in the case of what you described because you attached an *event listener* of event type *mouseup* to element A. I would conclude that particular mouseup event listener will not fire if you release the mouse button while hovering over anything not contained within element A.

Comment: I have mouseup listener on both elements actually

Comment: It seems the way it works under the hood is most likely that you have mouseup listener X on element A and mouseup listener Y on element B even though in your code it looks like you have the same event listener attached to both elements. Could you post your code?